# Showing Django view in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to pass a list of objects of my model Job to a template for display, but my template is showing up empty.

My **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Job

def job_list(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'student/profile.html', {'jobs': jobs})
```

My **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    minimum_cgpa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.company_id)
```

My template **student/profile.html**:

```
<p><br/>
  <ul>
    {% for job in jobs %}
    <li>{{ job.company }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>      
</p>
```

My db does contain 3 Job objects created in Admin. Running

```
Job.objects.all()
```

in the shell returns

```
<QuerySet [<Job: Job object>, <Job: Job object>, <Job: Job object>]>
```

I'm not getting any output in my template file. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Solved it. Was a dumb mistake on my part. Didn't call the job_list view def in my urls.py.

Comment: Basic but silly question - Does your db have any `Job` objects? You may use `python manage.py shell` and check interactively.

Comment: Yes, i used the shell to list the Job objects and it returns the one's I added in Admin.

Comment: In that case, given that your page isn't cached, check if `.company` has some value. Try inspecting the specific element. Your code seems to be correct, hence the checks.

Comment: The code seems to be right. Please, check that the regular expression for URL routing is also correct. You may be executing another view by error.

Comment: @VMRuiz There doesn't seem to be any errors in my urls.py:`url(r'^profile/$', student_profile_view, name='student-profile')` with the corresponding view being: `def student_profile_view(request): return render(request, 'student/profile.html')`

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Yes, company field does contain a value, as filter using a company name returns the Job object

Comment: If you are using `url(r'^profile/$', student_profile_view, name='student-profile')` and `def student_profile_view(request): return render(request, 'student/profile.html')` then you aren't executing `def job_list(request)`. Change it to: `url(r'^profile/$', job_list, name='student-profile')` or anything that make sense to you.

Comment: @VMRuiz *facepalm* Thanks dude, that solved it. That was a dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: No problem, your code was 100% so it was just a matter of finding the dumb mistake :)